# Lisp: list of nodes on a given level k

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, levels

I want to find all atoms from a tree, which are situated on a given level k. I tried something like:

```
(defun atoms (l)
  ;returns the list of atoms of l at its superficial level
  (cond
    ((null l) l)
    ((or (atom l) (numberp l)) l)
    ((or (atom (car l)) (numberp (car l))) 
      (append (list(car l)) (atom (cdr l))))
    (T (atoms (Cdr l)))))

(defun findat (l pos k)
  (cond
    ((null l) l)
    ((= k pos) (atoms l))
    ((and (or (atom l) (numberp l)) (= k pos)) l)
    (T (cons '() (mapcar #'(lambda (l) (findat l (+ pos 1) k)) l)))))
```

so, for the sample: *l=(a (b (g)) (c(d(e)) (f))), pos=0 and k=2*, I should get the result: *(g d f)*, but instead, I get some error saying that "A is not of type LIST". Does anyone have any idea, how to fix my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) This is another question where you talk about "non-linear list". I know [linear/non-linear data-structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures#Linear_data_structures) but I seldom encounter non-linear lists: is it a term used by a teacher or a textbook? I think you question would be clearer if you said "tree". (2) Please indent correctly your code (3) `defun` clearly identifies your code as `common-lisp`, please update your tags (4) Why do you write "my code"  in bold, like in your other question? How will you learn about alternative (maybe better) approaches?

Comment: I'm using "non-linear' term because that's how my teacher says. I will try to use  "tree", from now on. Also, you are right about the "my code" "problem". It's just that sometimes, I want to fix my code first, and of course that I'm open to any other different solutions. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: `(or (atom x) (numberp x))` contains a redundancy. All numbers are atoms! There is no way `(atom x)` can fail, yet `(numberp x)` succeed.

Comment: Yup.. I noticed that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a somewhat modified version of your `findat`. You might want to think of a better name for the function (at least write it out fully (`find-atoms`) instead of abbreviating unnecessarily).

```
(defun findat (l k)
  "Find atoms on level K in list L."
  (cond
    ((atom l) '())
    ((= k 0) (remove-if (complement #'atom) l))
    (t (mapcan #'(lambda (l)
                   (findat l (1- k)))
               l))))

(findat '(a (b (g)) (c (d (e)) (f))) 2)
; => (G D F)
```

Changes:

- I removed the argument `pos`. It's easier to simply count down with `k`.
- I changed the first case to check for atoms (which includes `nil`). It returns an empty list so that the `append` in the last case will discard it. Actually returning the wanted atoms is handled by the second case.
- I used the standard `remove-if` instead of your `atoms`. The call to `complement` produces a predicate that matches anything that is not an atom. Thus the `remove-if` only keeps atoms. You could also use `remove-if-not` and leave out the `complement`, but that's deprecated.
- In the last case, I used `(reduce #'append ...)` to create a flat list of the atoms. **Edit: Changed it to use `mapcan`.**

Notice also how I put a string at the beginning of the function. That's a docstring. You should do that instead of putting a comment there like in your `atoms`. That way you can use `(describe #'findat)` to see the documentation (or you can use your Emacs/IDE to view it).

Comment: `(reduce #'append (mapcar ...))` can be shortened as `mapcan`

Comment: @ jkiiski Thank you, it really helped me.

Comment: `(Complement #'atom)` is the same as `#'consp`.  The deprecation of the `-if-not` symbols in the standard is itself practically deprecated.  I believe `remove-if-not` is used more than `remove-if` in the wild.

Comment: @Svante Good point about `consp`, although I think using `atom` is better from a semantic point of view, as it makes it immediately clear to a reader that you want atoms. I know a lot of people use deprecated functions, but personally I prefer to avoid them whenever possible (and convenient enough). I guess it's just a matter of staying consistent across a project.